# How to create and write an image file from a base64 string using FileSystemFileHandle interface

Tags: javascript, image, file

I have a base64 string I am trying to create an image file from using the Javascript FileSystemFileHandle interface.

Name is a string from a text box on the page and is used to name the file, and content is a string with 'data:image/jpg;base64,' followed by the base64 string. The file handle is successfully created in the getNewFileHandle function, but when I open the file after the image is written to the file, windows says the file format is unsupported.

```
async function saveNewFile(name, content) {
    let fileHandle = await getNewFileHandle(name);

    const file = await fileHandle.createWritable();

    await file.write(content);

    await file.close();

    return;
}
```

The function used to create the file handle is the same as [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showSaveFilePicker) aside from supplying a suggested name to the file. I can confirm that it does create a file.

```
 //Creates Save File Window, creates writable file. Called from saveNewFile
    async function getNewFileHandle(name) {
        const opts = {
            suggestedName: name,
            types: [{
            description: 'Image file',
            accept: {'application/octet-stream': ['.jpg']},
          }],
        };
        return await window.showSaveFilePicker(opts);
      }
```

Does the interface not allow for writing images? I'm able to create a hyperlink that can succesfully download the image, but it's important to have save file picker appear.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I figured this out. I had to create a blob for the base64 data.